# How to normalize a projective curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am currently preparing for an algebraic geometry exam and I am trying to understand how to normalize a projective curve given by a homogeneous polynomial. For example let's consider the curve given by $$xy^2-xz^2-yz^2\in\Gamma(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}_k^2}(3),\mathbb{P}_k^2)$$
From what I understand it should suffice to normalize the curves in the affine charts of projective space and glue those curves afterwards. In this case we can see (for example using the Jacobian criterion) that on the charts $D(y)$ and $D(z)$ the curve is already normal. On $D(x)$ however we can see that $y^2-z^2-yz^2$ has a singularity in $(0,0)\in\mathbb{A}^2_k(k)$ so we have to normalize the curve in by computing the noether normalization of the coordinate ring $$k[y,z]/(y^2-z^2-yz^2)$$ this will turn out to be $k[\frac{y}{z}]$. My question is how do get from here to the final normalized curve in $\mathbb{P}_k^2$ i.e. how do I glue the normalized parts appropriatley?

Comment: Why the restrictions to $D(y),D(z)$ are normal?

Comment: If I did everything correctly you can check this by computing the Jacobian matrices for the two respective curves on $D(y)$ and $D(z)$ and check that they have full rank on all respective $k$-rational points.

Comment: You shouldn't expect that the normalization of a singular curve in $\mathbb{P}^2$ admits an embedding into $\mathbb{P}^2$. For example, if the normalization has genus $g = 2$, by the genus-degree formula.

Comment: In your case, the normalization will be isomorphic to $\mathbb{P}^1$, so there is an embedding into $\mathbb{P}^2$. However, I'm not sure there's a natural way to do so.